# Pass a closure to an array value

Tags: php, arrays, closures, preg-replace

Please forgive me if I'm way off here but I'm trying to create a simple template parser and to do this I'm using regular expressions to find template tags and replace them with dynamic text.

I want to be able to use a closure to return the replacement text. For example:

```
// Example 1
$tag['\{{title:(.*)}}\'] = function($1)
{
    return $1;
};

// Example 2
$tag['\{{title:(.*)}}\'] = function($1)
{
    $something = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
    return $1 . implode($something);
};

// Now do the replacements
foreach($tag as $pattern=>$replacement)
{
    preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $template);
}
```

I've included example 2 to explain that the result maybe dynamic and this is why I can't simply use strings.

I also feel like I need to explain why I'd need such functionality. The patterns are meant to be expandable, so other developers can add their own patterns easily.

If I've completely off the mark and this isn't going to be achievable, could you point me in the direction to achieve the same/similar functionality?

*also, side note - not my main question -* but is there a way to do multiple preg_replace in one go instead of looping through, seems inefficient.

Comment: To answer your last queston: `preg_replace` takes arrays as arguments, read the documentation [Link](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) on the parameters.

Comment: have a look at `preg_replace_callback()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: @Calimero this is EXACTLY what you need. Thank you :D

Comment: `preg_replace_callback_array` ([Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback-array.php), it has an example which is **very** similar to your use-case it seems) might be of use aswell.